# Function to change style.display of a div when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new to javascript and, starting from some code found on this site, I'm trying to change the visibility of a div using a function.

The function is

```
var MyClass = document.getElementsByClassName("DivMainSH");
var myFunction = function() {
    var SenderId = this.id;
    var IdNums = SenderId.split("_");
    var SubDivId = 'DivSubSH_' + IdNums[1];
    var SubDiv = document.getElementById(SubDivId);
    if (SubDiv.style.display = 'none'){
        alert("I'm here"); // This works
        SubDiv.style.display = 'blok'; // this doesn't work
        document.getElementById(SubDivId).style.display = 'blok'; // this doesn't work
    }else{
        document.getElementById(SubDivId).style.display = 'none';
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < MyClass.length; i++) {
    MyClass[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

The code works and I see the alert but the hidden div remains hidden.
I've tried many different approaches but no one worked.
**I'm sure it's some stupid beginner mistake** but I'm stuck with this since three days.
**EDIT**
The "else" part still not working after the typo correction

The php code I'm using to write the html is the following:

```
$Des_N_Vals=array("FirstName"=>"FirstDescr", 
          "SecondName"=>"SecondDescr",
          "ThirdName"=>"ThirdDescr");
DivShowHide_Insert('Select options', $Des_N_Vals);
Function DivShowHide_Insert($Name, $Arr_NameVal_Descr){
    $Name=str_replace(' ', '_', $Name);
    $Num=0;
    foreach($Arr_NameVal_Descr as $Val => $Descr) {
        echo '<div class="DivMainSH" id="DivMainSH_'.$Num.'">
                  <h3>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="'.$Name.'['.$Num.']" ';
        if (isset($_POST[$Name][$Num]) && $_POST[$Name][$Num]==$Val) echo ' checked="checked" ';
                        echo 'value="'.$Val.'">'.$Val.'</input>
                  </h3>
                <div class="DivSubSH" id="DivSubSH_'.$Num.'" style="display:none;">
                    '.$Descr.'
                </div>
            </div>';
        $Num++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have misspelt 'block'.

```
SubDiv.style.display = 'blok';
document.getElementById(SubDivId).style.display = 'blok';
```

Change this to:

```
SubDiv.style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(SubDivId).style.display = 'block';
```

And also, you are actually assigning a value to `SubDiv.style.display` in your following if statement:

```
if (SubDiv.style.display = 'none') {
```

This is causing the condition to always be true since the assignment never fails and so the display style of the div is always `none`, hence your div initially being hidden but never coming back.

```
if (SubDiv.style.display == 'none') {
```

Comment: I was sure it was a stupid mistake ... but not so stupid! Thanks!

Comment: But still not working fine: it shows the hiddem div but doesn't hide it when I click again

Comment: You are also using `=` instead of `==` in an if statement

Comment: You are right again but ... the else still not works. Sorry if it seems like a game (found the stupid mistakes)

Comment: Haha no problem, I think for everyone to help you better, please provide the rendered HTML so it can be debugged in a jsfiddle or something

Comment: At the moment I'm AFK but I've already posted the php code that generates the html. Hope you can use it

Comment: Hi, I've accepted, because I've tested the posted code and it works fine (after removing mistakes) So there must be some other stupid error somewhere else in my code. I'll try to catch it. Thanks again for your help. ;)